# How do I change the order of the x axis in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, matplotlib, graph

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
G_pop = wb.download(indicator='SP.POP.TOTL', country="DEU", end=2020, start=2010)
G_pop = G_pop.reset_index(1)

G_pop.columns = ["year", "Population in Germany"]
pd.set_option("display.max.columns", 100000)
pd.set_option("display.max.rows", 300000)
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000000)
x = G_pop["year"]
y = G_pop["Population in Germany"]
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='left')

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I'm new to programming and am trying to modulate graphs with the World Bank database. It works quite well apart from my X-axis. Does anyone know how I can convert them? Since the left is 2000 and the right is 2020 ascending. It is currently the case that the left on the x axis is 2020 and it is descending. I've been struggling with this problem for two days and can't get any further. `invert_xaxis()` and `invert_yaxis()`. I've tried both and it only gives me error messages. I would be very thankful for any help.

My code and the Graph wit the wrong x `axis`:

[image: My code and the Graph wit the wrong x axis]

Picture of the wrong Graph:

[image: Picture of the wrong Graph]

Comment: Please include your code *as code-formatted text* in the question. It's much more difficult to interpret a screen shot of code. An image of your graph on the other hand is entirely appropriate. You should also tag the libraries you're using, [tag:matplotlib] and [tag:pandas] are much more relevant than your OS or the generic [tag:graph] or [tag:analysis] tags.

Comment: what if you change start and end values?

Comment: I had the same idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work, it gives me the error message

"ValueError: start must be an earlier date than end"

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for the advice. I hope Is now better.

Comment: @Ricca: Looks good to me! Unfortunately, my Pandas knowledge is pretty sparse, but I hope you'll get somebody who can answer the question for you.

Comment: @Blckknght anyway thanks for the try and your time

Comment: If any answer does what you want, tell it to the community by accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:

```
G_pop.columns = ["year", "Population in Germany"]
G_pop['year'] = pd.to_numeric(G_pop['year']) # Convert text to numeric for automatic sorting
pd.set_option("display.max.columns", 100000)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: your are a hero. Thanks a lot for you time and effort !!!!!!! you made my week!!!!

Comment: Thank you, @Ricca.  You've made my week also!  Happy coding.